# Why is my domain name working but not displaying in address bar in Heroku app?

Tags: heroku, dns

I have a domain name www.terapianutricional.net and this redirects to my heroku app https://bootstrapp3.herokuapp.com

The problem is that the domain works and redirects, but after loading the heroku app address is displayed. I expect the domain name to be visible.

Note: this domain name was in active for a few months and it has just been purchased again. I can post any further information if needed.  please advise.

Comment: Pls check that the DNS **resolves** (not redirects) to your heroku app... This is usually from some docs your DNS provider has..

Comment: You may also need to configure your production domain within your application so it can generate links properly.

Comment: @Chris please could you tell me bowto check this. as i said it was set up correctly a few months ago but the domain expired so i renewed. the only thing i changed was creating a redirect becuase the domain wasnt working at all. but as Kwame says above this was not the right hting to do

Comment: @KwameOpareAsiedu i have never heard of resolves. please could you explain further. i did indeed set up a redirect which was the wrong thing to do.

Comment: @Owen, that depends entirely on the application you're running.

Comment: @Chris it is a heroku app. just a simple website

Comment: Heroku has nothing to do with what I'm talking about. What does "a simple website" mean? Static HTML?

Comment: @Owen ***Redirecting*** is essentially saying if I visit site A and the request hits the DNS, respond with a redirect to site B (This will change the URL in the address bar of your window). ***Resolving*** is essentially saying if I visit site A and the request hits the DNS, reroute the request to the connected application's URL (Site B) and return it's response to the user. (This does not change the URL in the address bar but will serve up Site B's content still on the URL of Site A) ...

Comment: @KwameOpareAsiedu that sounds like what i need to do. but i dom tsee the word resolve anywhere on internetBS website. only redirect option

Comment: @Chris i didnt understand what you meant by depends on the application you 're running. I dont have much experience with this. although i got the site on line 2 years ago i have forgotten how i did it. I remember doing somethign with the CNAME. but i think it is all done already i just renewed the domain name by paying for it. i thought it would work as before but something has changed and i am completely lost

Comment: Perhaps... they're using a different term for it... Since you have purchased a domain with them, you could contact them on customer support how to set it up... cos it may differ from provider to provider...